# perplexing code execution path with decorators in python

Tags: python, decorator

I'm getting into Python and just struggling a bit with this piece of example code from the "Real Python" site.

```
import functools

def count_calls(func):
    def wrapper_count_calls(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapper_count_calls.num_calls += 1
        print(f"Call {wrapper_count_calls.num_calls} of {func.__name__!r}")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper_count_calls.num_calls = 0
    return wrapper_count_calls

@count_calls
def say_whee():
    print("Whee!")
```

Here's the output given a couple of calls to the "say_whee" function.

```
>>> say_whee()
Call 1 of 'say_whee'
Whee!

>>> say_whee()
Call 2 of 'say_whee'
Whee!

>>> say_whee.num_calls
2
```

The bit that's perplexing is that the line "wrapper_count_calls.num_calls = 0" does not seem to be executed when the "say_whee" function is called even though it has the decorator "@count_calls"

Comment: The decorator function is executed when the other function is decorated, not when the other function is called.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstood the concept of decorators a little bit.

`count_calls` will only be called once, i.e. when you use it to decorate `say_whee`. For example, run this code:

```
import functools

def count_calls(func):
    def wrapper_count_calls(*args, **kwargs):
        print("wrapper_count_calls is called")
        wrapper_count_calls.num_calls += 1
        print(f"Call {wrapper_count_calls.num_calls} of {func.__name__!r}")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper_count_calls.num_calls = 0
    print("count_calls is called")
    return wrapper_count_calls

@count_calls
def say_whee():
    print("Whee!")
```

**Output**

```
count_calls is called
```

But when the actual `say_whee` is called, only `wrapper_count_calls` runs:

```
say_whee()
```

```
wrapper_count_calls is called
Call 1 of 'say_whee'
Whee!
```

Comment: Hi mrzo, Yes thank you for your response. I put a print where you had one but was trying to work out how it was called once only.  Thank you for your help with this.  Much clearer now!

Comment: The confusion for me stems from coming from a compiled C / C++ background where all declarations are done before execution.  Whereas, of course, with Python, execution / Interpretation occurs immediately after the definition of an object.  Consequently the call to the decorator occurs immediately after the definition of the function / class.

Answer (score 1):

> The bit that's perplexing is that the line "wrapper_count_calls.num_calls = 0" does not seem to be executed when the "say_whee" function is called even though it has the decorator "@count_calls"

Decorators are an almost trivial bit of syntactic sugar:

```py
@foo
def bar():
    ...
```

desugars to:

```py
def bar():
    ...
bar = foo(bar)
```

and that's about it.

Since the line which initially sets the attribute is at the toplevel of the decorator it's executed when the decorator itself is called, which is right after the function is defined.

It then "replaces" the function it decorates by the inner `wrapper_count_calls`, which is what gets called (and calls the wrapped function), incrementing the attribute.

Comment: Hi Masklinn, Yes thank you for your response. I was previously thinking that the foo(bar) statement would be executed each time rather than the proc that was referenced in bar.

Comment: The confusion for me stems from coming from a compiled C / C++ background where all declarations are done before execution.  Whereas, of course, with Python, execution / Interpretation occurs immediately after the definition of an object.  Consequently the call to the decorator occurs immediately after the definition of the function / class.